# Serial execution of package tests

Tags: testing, go

I have implemented several packages for a web API, each with their own test cases. When each package is tested using `go test ./api/pkgname` the tests pass. If I want to run all tests at once with `go test ./api/...` test cases always fail.

In each test case, I recreate the entire schema using `DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE` followed by `CREATE SCHEMA public` and apply all migrations. The test suite reports errors back at random, saying a relation/table does not exist, so I guess each test suite (per package) is run in parallel somehow, thus messing up the DB state.

I tried to pass along some test flags like `go test -cpu 1 -parallel 0 ./src/api/...` with no success.

Could the problem here be tests running in parallel, and if yes, how can I force serial execution?

***Update:***

Currently I use this workaround to run the tests, but I still wonder if there's a better solution

```
find <dir> -type d -exec go test {} \;
```

Comment: Maybe this is not a Go problem, but a testing problem. Tests should not have a global state (like a connection to a database), thus should be able to run in parallel.

Comment: Well, then how do you propose one should test an API that relies on a Db? Mocking everything would just defeat the tests purpose.

Comment: I'm not a fan of global test state myself, but I see no other option here.

Comment: While ideally these tests would be unit tests, I can't see any justification for -parallel=0 being ignored when running on multiple packages. That sounds like the real bug here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As others have pointed out, -parallel doesn't do the job (it only works within packages). However, you can use the flag -p=1 to run through the package tests in series. This is documented here:

http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/testflag.go

but (afaict) not on the command line, go help, etc. I'm not sure it is meant to stick around (although I'd argue that if it is removed, -parallel should be fixed.)

Comment: This worked perfectly for us in the exact same scenario.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Although I can't see any reference to this flag in the page you linked to. Maybe they removed the documentation for this?

Comment: The -p flag is shown in the output of `go help build`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me! I was considering all kinds of crazy workarounds like creating a separate database for each package (yikes) - glad it ended up being so simple.

Comment: BTW that link is 404 now

Comment: go test -test.parallel 1

Answer (score 9):

The go tool is provided to make running unit tests easier using the convention that *_test.go files contain unittests in them. Because it assumes they are unittests it also assumes they are hermetic. It sounds like your tests either aren't unittests or they are but violate the assumptions that a unittest should fulfill.

In the case that you mean for these tests to be unittests then you probably need a mock database for your unittests. A mock, preferrably in memory, of your database will ensure that the unittest is hermetic and can't be interfered with by other unittests.

In the case that you mean for these tests to be integration tests you are probably better off not using the go tool for these tests. What you probably want is to create a seperate test binary whose running you can control and write you integration test scripts in there.

The good news is that creating a mock in Go is insanely easy. Change your code to take an interface with the methods you care about for the databases and then write an in memory implementation of that interface for testing purposes and pass it into your application code that you want to test.

Comment: Yes, I know I could mock it, but I actually want to hit the database, which is why I probably will move the tests to a separate binary.

Comment: It's actually surprisingly easy to set up a separate integration test `main.go` since `testing` exports `testing.Main`.

Comment: yeah, That's part of the reason I suggested it :-p

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, @Jeremy's answer is still the accepted one:

Since my integration tests were only run on one package (`api`), I removed the separate test binary in the end and created a pattern to separate test types by:

- Unit tests use the normal `TestX` name
- Integration tests use `Test_X`

I created shell scripts (`utest.sh`/`itest.sh`) to run either of those.

- For unit tests `go test -run="^(Test|Benchmark)[^_](.*)"`
- For integration tests `go test -run"^(Test|Benchmark)_(.*)"`
- Run both using the normal `go test`

Comment: Thanks for following up, this was useful when running into the same scenario.